# Transform array to the following format

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that have 2 fields key and type, the type field is practice or theory

Result:

1. group the array by key
2. transform the array: in the new array the object with type practice should come in the even index and object with type theory should be in the odd index. (check the input and the output if my explanation wasn't clear)

here's my code but it doesn't work as expected in the transform the array

```
function transformArray(arr) {
  const grouped = arr.reduce((result, item) => {
    const key = item.key;
    if (!result[key]) {
      result[key] = { key, values: [] };
    }
    result[key].values.push(item);
    return result;
  }, {});

  for (const group in grouped) {
    const values = grouped[group].values;
    const newValues = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      const item = values[i];
      if (item.type === 'practice' && i % 2 === 0) {
        newValues.push(item);
      } else if (item.type === 'theory' && i % 2 === 1) {
        newValues.push(item);
      }
    }
    grouped[group].values = newValues;
  }

  return Object.values(grouped);
}
```

example input:

```
const input = [
{ key: 'A', type: 'practice' },
{ key: 'A', type: 'practice' },
{ key: 'A', type: 'theory' },
{ key: 'A', type: 'theory' },

{ key: 'B', type: 'practice' },
{ key: 'B', type: 'theory' },
{ key: 'B', type: 'practice' },

{ key: 'C', type: 'practice' },
{ key: 'C', type: 'theory' },
{ key: 'C', type: 'practice' },
]
```

OUTPUT should be like the following

```
[
  {
    key: 'A',
    values: [
      { key: 'A', type: 'practice'},  // index = even ==> practice
      { key: 'A', type: 'theory' },    // index = odd ==> theory
      { key: 'A', type: 'practice'}, // index = even ==> practice
      { key: 'A', type: 'theory'}, // index = odd ==> theory
    ],
  },
  {
    key: 'B',
    values: [
      { key: 'B', type: 'practice' },
      { key: 'B', type: 'theory',},
      { key: 'B', type: 'practice' },
    ],
  },
  {
    key: 'C',
    values: [
      { key: 'C', type: 'practice' },
      { key: 'C', type: 'theory', },
      { key: 'C', type: 'practice'},
    ],
  },
]
```

my code is kinda broken, and I wonder how to achieve this output?

Comment: Please give a [mre] - what does _"doesn't work as expected"_ mean?

Comment: I have input and output, and I explained in details how it should work

Comment: it looks like alternating practice and theory. why all the if checks. cant you just replace 0,2..

Comment: @cmgchess can you explain in more details please

Comment: i meant why not something like `values.forEach((e,i) => i%2===0 ? e.type = 'practice' : e.type = 'theory');` . without having to write newValues and grouped[group].values = newValues;

Comment: @cmgchess I can't do that because the object has more fields(not just `type` and `key`) , but I didn't add them here because it would be useless

and if I do your solutions it means I am changing the object and I don't want to do that

Comment: if you dont want to mutate then you use map. also you can expand the logic . i just 1 lined it here

Comment: @cmgchess can you provide code snippet

Comment: `const newValues = values.map((e,i) => {
     const type = i%2===0 ? 'practice' :'theory'
      return ({...e,type})
    });
    grouped[group].values = newValues;`

Comment: @cmgchess
`const type = i % 2 === 0 ? 'practice' : 'theory';
      return { ...e, type };`

this code will mutate the object I don't want to do that

Comment: so make a copy of grouped and change it?

Comment: @cmgchess how ?

Comment: btw what shouldnt be mutated. the function values of grouped Object and the output then shows mutated grouped object

Comment: the objects can't be mutated we can't replace type with type

Comment: i get it i think. u need to jumble them and not change so that it form alternate practice and theory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you not to squash everything into one function but instead implement a few small utility functions (you can use a library like `lodash` for that).

So you have 2 separate util steps

1. Group array by key and then by type
2. Interleave two arrays for practice and theory.

```js
function transform(arr) {
  const result = []

  for (const [key, value] of groupBy('key', arr).entries()) {
    const byType = groupBy('type', value)

    result.push({
      key,
      values: interleave(
        byType.get('practice') ?? [], byType.get('theory') ?? [],
      ),
    })
  }

  return result

}


const input = [{"key":"A","type":"practice"},{"key":"A","type":"practice"},{"key":"A","type":"theory"},{"key":"A","type":"theory"},{"key":"B","type":"practice"},{"key":"B","type":"theory"},{"key":"B","type":"practice"},{"key":"C","type":"practice"},{"key":"C","type":"theory"},{"key":"C","type":"practice"}]

console.log(transform(input))

// Utils
function groupBy(by, arr) {
  const out = new Map

  for (const item of arr) {
    const key = item[by]

    if (out.has(key)) {
      out.get(key).push(item)
    } else {
      out.set(key, [item])
    }
  }

  return out
}

function interleave(a, b) {
  const out = []
  const len = Math.max(a.length, b.length)

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (i < a.length) out.push(a[i])
    if (i < b.length) out.push(b[i])
  }

  return out
}
```